# Mediawiki mode stopped working after upgrading to the latest 20150403

Tags: package

In Emacs 24.3.1, I upgraded Mediawiki package to the latest version, 20150403...,  using the package manager.  After restarting, I found that I can't access remote Mediawiki sites any more, after inputting user name and password as usual, I got a

```
Wrong type argument: listp, 0
```

error in the mini buffer.  Anybody else?  Any idea how to fix it?

Edit:

This is what I get in a backtrace buffer:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp 0)
  mediawiki-page-get-revision((page ((pageid . "1") (ns . "0") (title . "Main Page") (contentmodel . "wikitext") (pagelanguage . "en") (touched . "2014-03-12T04:57:54Z") (lastrevid . "505") (counter . "2691") (length . "141") (starttimestamp . "2015-05-29T07:52:26Z") (edittoken . "b3b54027c1c571738764f73dee1e4abd+\\")) (revisions nil (rev ((revid . "505") (parentid . "454") (user . "XXX") (timestamp . "2014-03-12T04:57:54Z") (comment . "") (contentformat . "text/x-wiki") (contentmodel . "wikitext") (xml:space . "preserve")) "Main page."))) 0 timestamp)
  mediawiki-save-metadata("1" (page ((pageid . "1") (ns . "0") (title . "Main Page") (contentmodel . "wikitext") (pagelanguage . "en") (touched . "2014-03-12T04:57:54Z") (lastrevid . "505") (counter . "2691") (length . "141") (starttimestamp . "2015-05-29T07:52:26Z") (edittoken . "b3b54027c1c571738764f73dee1e4abd+\\")) (revisions nil (rev ((revid . "505") (parentid . "454") (user . "XXX") (timestamp . "2014-03-12T04:57:54Z") (comment . "") (contentformat . "text/x-wiki") (contentmodel . "wikitext") (xml:space . "preserve")) "Main page."))))
  mediawiki-get("1" "Main Page")
  mediawiki-edit("1" "Main_Page")
  mediawiki-site()
  call-interactively(mediawiki-site record nil)
  command-execute(mediawiki-site record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "mediawiki-site")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Comment: Maybe you should upgrade to latest Emacs 24.5.

Comment: Tried that to no avail.

Comment: Fails for me as well with emacs 24.5 and latest mediawiki from melpa

Comment: You might want to report that issue on the bug tracker for the package: https://github.com/hexmode/mediawiki-el

Comment: I'd like to help, but I need the backtrace.  That, or which (public) wiki you are trying this on.

(Sorry about the delay in responding... someone pinged me about this while I was at a conference.)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing lines 177 and following from:

```
  (cadr revision))
 ((assoc bit (car revision))
  (cdr (assoc bit (car revision))))
 (t revision))))
```

to:

```
  (cadr rev))
 ((assoc bit (car rev))
  (cdr (assoc bit (car rev))))
 (t rev))))
```

Comment: Since I reported the issue, I restored the older version when the project hadn't moved to GitHub, and it worked.  Now I'll try your fix.  I still hope the official author of the mode could fix it in the official version.